# How can I run this line of ruby code without eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following piece of code, where params[:sort] is a variable whose value is one of m's column.

```
eval "@movie = @movie.sort_by { |m| m.#{params[:sort]}}"
```

Basically I want to sort the array @movie according to the column specified. Is there any way to do this without eval?

Comment: I personally like to sort movies by the key "destroy".

Comment: also, the pattern `var = f(var)` is pretty dubious, why not create a new variable for the new value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@movie = @movie.sort_by { |m| m.send(params[:sort])}
```

You need to sanitize `params[:sort]` to prevent calling `destroy` for example.

Comment: For whitelisting the columns, check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns -- you are sorting the columns after getting them from the database, the railscast shows how to make the database do the sorting first.

Answer (score 1):

As told before, you should use `send` and as you use `params` (which I assume is Rails), you should probably check if the method exists to avoid a `NoMethodError` exception and, even better, test against a white list to prevent some user to use it to get data they shouldn't have.

```
# Just for the example :
valid_sort_methods = Movie.new.attributes.keys - Movie.protected_attributes.to_a

if valid_sort_methods.include? params[:sort]
  @movie = @movie.sort_by { |m| m.send params[:sort] }
end
```

Comment: idea for an abstraction, Object#whitelist: `"white".whitelist("black", "white") #=> "white"`, `"blue".whitelist("black", "white") #=> nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `send` to call the accessor method. Depending on where `params[:sort]` has come from and what sanitisation has been applied, this could still be dangerous. You wouldn't want `params[:sort]` to be `destroy` for example.

If you only intend to read attributes then the simplest thing is probably to call `read_attribute`, which is also aliased as `[]`, for example

```
@movie = @movie.sort_by { |m| m[params[:sort]]}
```